# Is the @After annotation always executed in Selenium when an exception occurs?

Tags: selenium

In the case of an exception occuring; is it necessary to close the driver in a catch block when writing a Selenium test case?
I closed the driver in the tearDown() method which has the `@After` annotation.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to close/quit the driver in catch block if you have done that in `@After` annotation.

Here.

> All @After methods are guaranteed to run even if a Before or Test
>   method throws an exception.

taken from following website 
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html

as it doesn't matter exception has occurred or not this annotation is going to be executed.

Following example is using **TestNG** but I think `@After` annotation of **JUnit** is same as `@AfterMethod` of **TestNG**

In below example, even though test will throw `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` the `tearDown` method will be executed and will close all the browsers.

```
public class GoogleTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("Closed all the browsers");
    }

    @Test
    public void visitGoogle(){
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        int a=1/0;
    }

}
```

In the Junit report you will see two thing.

**Error**: if any exception has occurred it will be reported as error

**Failure**: if any assertions has failed then it will be reported as Failure

I wouldn't handle the exception until you want to continue the flow. Exception like `ElementNotFound` or `ElementNotVisible` of webdriver is better unhandled.  It will fail the test and you can see the whole stack trace, which will help you debug the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

@After is nothing to do with selenium. It is an annotation of JUNIT if you are using java. There is no such rule to close driver in tearDown() or specify @After function. While it is good practice to quit driver instance once the testcase done. quit will close all your browser instances and clear memory and resources in machine if another script going to trigger. 
Moreover, handling the error is also a good practice. You should handle the errors which can occur during script execution in runtime. example :- I/O operation, file upload etc

Example :-

```
  WebDriver driver=null;
 @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    //driver.quit();
    System.out.println("Closed all the browsers");
}

@Test
public void visitGoogle(){
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    try {
    int a=1/0;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: How can i close or quit driver if an exception occurs ?

Comment: @ShubhamJain `If exception occurs then your @After method will not execute so you have to write quit in exception. specially in generic exception block` is not correct.

Comment: Yes I found it as mistake.. @After will execute

Answer (score 0):

Small update: there is an option in testNG for annonations i.e. beforetest, aftertest. And that option is @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)...once this is set then the @AfterTest will always execute even if there was exception in the methods before.